# Access point with hostapd on ubuntu 20.04 server won't let clients connect

Tags: netplan, hostapd

I've got an ubuntu gateway server with 2 network cards, on for the internet and one for the lan. I've just set up the wireless access point on the wireless device using `hostapd` but the clients fail to connect to it with this error in the logs:

```
Dec 12 10:08:56 localhost hostapd: wlp6s0: STA 84:cf:bf:91:d8:35 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Dec 12 10:08:56 localhost hostapd: wlp6s0: STA 84:cf:bf:91:d8:35 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Dec 12 10:09:05 localhost hostapd: wlp6s0: STA 84:cf:bf:91:d8:35 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
```

I have managed to put the configuration together so far pretty much by guesswork and finding individual steps in various places, because I couldn't find any how-to guide that covered ubuntu, `netplan`, and `hostapd`.

This is my setup:

hostapd.conf:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
interface=wlp6s0
driver=nl80211
bridge=br0
ssid=Anduin
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=secret123
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

netplan:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - fe80::10/128
      - 192.168.0.3/24
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    wlp6s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

Answer (score 0):

Still no clear idea about why the deauth messages appeared, but I solved the `hostapd` issues by setting up the bridge in netplan.

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    wlp6s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - wlp6s0
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.3/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [208.67.220.220,208.67.222.222]
adam@gondolin:~$
```